# “Could not find an installed version of Gradle” in ionic 3

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to build Android using `ionic cordova build android`

where I am facing problem in  -->

> Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
>   Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please
>   include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio

I am sharing more details that I got after `ionic cordova build android`

```
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Users/user/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
studio
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```